# Does "test-keys" mean device is rooted?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode

I have Android phone that fails to boot after working happily some time.

I'm trying to install official firmware update zip from manufacturer's site, but update fails with errors:

```
  E: footer is wrong
  E: signature verification failed
  E: install package error, result = 7
```

Google results suggest that official updates can fail integrity verification only if the device is rooted (yes, I've re-downloaded the update several times, the file is ok). As the phone does not boot, I cannot use the "root check" app or terminal etc. On top of the recovery menu, after the ROM version (I guess) there's a line: **user/test-keys**.

**Is this a sign that the device is rooted?**

Comment: I don't think so but which device?

Comment: [HOMTOM HT16](http://www.homtom.cc/Product/ProductDetail?proId=11) Purchased 3 months ago. The user does not remember rooting it but I guess it could be remotely hacked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It means that firmware on your device is not signed by release keys and is vulnerable**

- [Signing Builds for Release  |  Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds) explains *test keys* as compared to *release keys* in building a ROM or OS

> The Android tree includes *test-keys* under `build/target/product/security`. Building an Android OS image using `make` will sign all .apk files using the test-keys. Since the test-keys are publicly known, **anybody can sign their own .apk files with the same keys, which may allow them to replace or hijack system apps** built into your OS image. For this reason it is critical to sign any publicly released or deployed Android OS image with a special set of release-keys that only you have access to.

(Emphasis Supplied)

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18808705) supports

> Release-Keys and Test-Keys has to do with how the kernel is signed when it is compiled. Release-Keys means it was signed with an official Key from an official developer. Test-Keys means it was signed with a custom key generated by a third-party developer. From a security standpoint Release-Keys generally means the kernel is more secure, which is not always the case

and hence is a security risk as reiterated in this [XDA post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/security-test-keys-vs-release-keys-t1937469)

**Does it mean my device is rooted?**

The fact that you have not been able to apply official firware updates ( which check for root  ) indicates that the device may be rooted  (in addition ).  You can verify in alternate ways (other than apps ) as mentioned here [How can I tell if I have root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13335/131553)

Related [Can I 'trick' my device into thinking it's unrooted?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/59108)

Comment: beeshyams, I didn't remember installing other firmware updates on this phone before. What official updates do you mean: apps from the Google Store?

Comment: So, the line "user/test-keys" does mean that the current firmware (whatever it is) built with these test keys?